# How can I determine if a previous route is external

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm using Angular `location.goBack` navigation.
I would like to disable a back navigation button if the next `goBack` execution will navigate outside of the app.

Is there a best practice way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe [CanDeactivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate) guard could be useful here.

Comment: @Andrei Gătej thank! I'm trying to indicate to the user that they can't navigate back before they do so.

Answer (score 2):

This thing is really tricky. Browser history  didn't provide a way to handle URLs. You can just do  back. So, you detect navigation outside  your app you have to implement  your own history log.

But  better avoid copping  in  app default  browser functionality, because you will catch a lot of tricky bugs.